# Return to previous status on mouseout event jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, mouseover, mouseout

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27bvG/

This show "hidden" li on mouseover and remain visible
I'm not so skilled with Jquery, so I need some help.
How can i return to previous state on mouseout and show again "2 more"?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
     $("#tricky_list li.more").hover(
        function () {
           // hover function       
        }

     },
        function () {
         // unhover function
       }
    );
```

in the hover function you can show your different li and in the unhover you can hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by handling the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events for the LIs you display on hovering over the "2 more" LI. See code below.

**Check this demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/27bvG/8/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="tricky_list">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li class="onmore">Item 4</li>
<li class="onmore">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var hideTimer = -1;
$("#tricky_list li.more").on("mouseover", function(){
    $("#tricky_list li.onmore").show();
    $("#tricky_list li.more").hide()
});
$("#tricky_list li.onmore").on("mouseover", function(){
    clearTimeout(hideTimer);
    hideTimer = -1;
});
$("#tricky_list li.onmore").on("mouseout", function(){
    hideTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#tricky_list li.more").show();
        $("#tricky_list li.onmore").hide();
        hideTimer = -1;
    }, 1000);
});
```